# decode JavaScript code ?

Tags: javascript, decode, blogger, deobfuscation

I found this code in the blog template,Already used it. I am afraid to be harmful blog,Or be an injection ..I'm trying to decode it but failed , so please help ? because i want to be sure what is it ,

```
document.write( unescape( '%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%27%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%61%72%6C%69%6E%61%2D%64%65%73%69%67%6E%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%63%6F%64%65%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%73%76%6E%2F%76%69%65%77%6D%65%2E%6A%73%27%20%74%79%70%65%3D%27%74%65%78%74%2F%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%27%2F%3E'
))
```

Comment: Just console.log it instead of writing it to the dom. `<script src='https://arlina-design.googlecode.com/svn/viewme.js' type='text/javascript'/>`

Comment: Open your console, paste it in, remove the `document.write(`…`)`, run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
console.log( unescape( '%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%27%68%74%74%70%73%3A%2F%2F%61%72%6C%69%6E%61%2D%64%65%73%69%67%6E%2E%67%6F%6F%67%6C%65%63%6F%64%65%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%73%76%6E%2F%76%69%65%77%6D%65%2E%6A%73%27%20%74%79%70%65%3D%27%74%65%78%74%2F%6A%61%76%61%73%63%72%69%70%74%27%2F%3E'
))
```

As suggested in the comments above, use console.log to view the contents. This yields `https://arlina-design.googlecode.com/svn/viewme.js` which seems to get a 404 error, but if the owner put it back up, then they could run that code-- the code that THEY control. If you include it, it can access your webpage, and it IS a security hole.

Comment: @ Feathercrown . thank you so much , clear answer , God Bless you

Comment: @k76 If this solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) the answer. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Comment: already accepted . you completely right .. but do you think will i keep it or erase it ?

Comment: 1. Always keep questions, even if they are answered. This allows future readers to see the solution.     2. To accept an answer on Stack Overflow, click the check-mark under the score to the left of the answer.      P.S. Thanks for that first comment! Always good to know I can help.